# Using an implementation of a Swift protocol within Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to implement a mediator sort of pattern with a mixture of Swift and Obj-C. The issue I'm facing is with how to deal with using the Swift protocol implementation classes from Obj-C.  Check out the code to see what I mean:

The Swift protocol and implementation of it:

```
@objc public protocol TheProtocol {
    func someMethod()
}

@objc public class SwiftClass: NSObject, TheProtocol {
    public func someMethod() {
        print("someMethod Swift")
    }
}
```

The ObjC-implementation of the protocol:

```
#import "SwiftAndObjC-Swift.h"
@interface ObjCClass : NSObject <TheProtocol>
- (void) someMethod;
@end


@implementation ObjCClass
- (void) someMethod
{
    NSLog(@"someMethod ObjC");
}
@end
```

My question is how is it possible to define some type in ObjC which is capable of referencing either a SwiftClass or an ObjCClass. For example this does not compile:

```
#import "SwiftAndObjC-Swift.h"
...
TheProtocol *p = [[ObjCClass alloc] init];
// Error: "Use of undeclared identifier TheProtocol"
```

This will compile:

```
@class TheProtocol
TheProtocol *p = [[ObjCClass alloc] init];
```

But not p can't be used:

```
@class TheProtocol
TheProtocol *p = [[ObjCClass alloc] init];
[p someMethod];
// Error: Receiver type "The Protocol" is a forward declaration"
```

(Adding casts to the assignment and/or method invocation doesn't help)

Any solutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Objective-C, a protocol is not a type. You should declare your protocol-conforming class like so:

```
id<TheProtocol> p = [[ObjCClass alloc] init];
```

The reason why your forward declaration compiled is because that's what forward declarations do - they announce to the compiler that a class exists and that the linker will fill it in later in the build process.

(That's why changing to `id p =...` works too.)

In Swift, we declare classes with something like:

```
class MyClass : Superclass, Protocol, AnotherProtocol { ... }
```

In Objective-C we use this:

```
@class MyClass : SuperClass <Protocol, AnotherProtocol>
// ... 
@end
```

See the difference? In Swift, protocols and the superclass are mixed into the inheritance declaration, whereas Objective-C treats them very differently.

Protocols and Classes are treated slightly different across the two languages, thus used differently.

`id` in ObjectiveC is analogous to `AnyObject?` in Swift. An object which conforms to `SomeProtocol` is obviously `AnyObject` or `id` in Objective-C.

Answer (score -1):

you don't use @class to declare a protocol... instead you have to import your Swift compatibility header which will contain your protocol definition.

Also to declare an object that conforms to a protocol in Obj C, use `id<TheProtocol>` as your type

Answer (score -2):

Solved it, I just changed the type to id

```
id p = [[ObjCClass alloc] init];
[p someMethod];
```

Comment: `id` is roughly equivalent to `AnyObject`. you probably want `id<TheProtocol>` which means an object that conforms to _TheProtocol_